# How to proof that a manifold covered by two charts satisfying $f_i(\mathbb{R}^m \setminus B^o) \subset f_j(B^o)$ for $i\not=j$ is simply connected?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, fundamental-groups, de-rham-cohomology

While studying for my comprehensive exam, I came across the following problem, which I am unable to solve.

Let $B$ denote the closed unit ball centered at the origin in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^m$, $\partial B$ denote the boundary sphere of $B$ and $B^o$ denote the interior of $B$.

Let $f_i: \mathbb{R}^m \to M$, $i=1,2$ denote smooth embeddings into a smooth $m$-dimensional manifold $M$ which satisfy

$$f_1(\mathbb{R}^m) \cup f_2(\mathbb{R}^m) = M$$
$$f_1(\mathbb{R}^m \setminus B^o) \subset f_2(B^o) $$
$$f_2(\mathbb{R}^m \setminus B^o) \subset f_1(B^o) $$

Suppose that $m \geq 2$. Show that $M$ is a simply connected closed manifold.

---

Here is what I have been able to do so far.

*Proof that M is closed:*
Let $\{x_i\}$ be a sequence in $M$, then we can subtract a subseqeunce $\{x_{i_j}\}$ which is contained entirely within $f_1(\mathbb{R}^m)$ or entirely within $f_2(\mathbb{R}^m)$. Suppose without loss of generality that $\{x_{i_j}\}$ is contained entirely within $f_1(\mathbb{R}^m)$, then we can subtract a subsubsequence $\{x_{i_{j_k}}\}$ which is contained entirely within $f_1(B)$ or entirely within $f_1(\mathbb{R}^m \setminus B^o)$. Suppose first that $\{x_{i_{j_k}}\}$ is contained entirely within $f_1(B)$ then by compactness of $f_1(B)$ there is subsubsubsequence $\{x_{i_{j_{k_l}}}\}$ which converges in $f_1(B)$. If instead the subsubsequence $\{x_{i_{j_k}}\}$ is contained entirely within $f_1(\mathbb{R}^m \setminus B^o)$, then by assumption the subsubsequence is contained within $f_2(B)$, which is compact, so there is a subsubsubsequence $\{x_{i_{j_{k_l}}}\}$ which converges. Hence $M$ is compact. Since $f_1$, and $f_2$ are charts without boundary that covers $M$, then $M$ is a manifold without boundary, so $M$ is closed.

I am unable to show that $M$ is simply connected. It is connected, as it is the union of two connected sets with non-empty intersection. If $f_1(\mathbb{R}^m) \cap f_2(\mathbb{R}^m)$ is connected then by the Seifert-Van Kampen Theorem $M$ would be simply connected. My idea has been to try and come up with suitable open subsets $U, V$ and then use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence to show that the 0th de Rham Cohomology group of $f_1(\mathbb{R}^m) \cap f_2(\mathbb{R}^m)$ has dimension 1. None of my candidates for $U$ and $V$ has worked so far.

The result fails when $m=1$ since then $M=S^1$. I am not sure how to invoke the $m \geq 2$ hypothesis, if the problem is to be solved without a Mayer-Vietoris argument.

The problem *should* be solvable using techniques from *Topology* (By Munkres) and *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (By Lee). This means no Generalized Jordan Curve Theorem, Reduced Integral Homology or Alexander Duality. Any help/solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a shorter argument about why $M$ is closed. It’s enough to show that $M$ is a compact topological space. But by your hypothesis $M=f_1(B) \cup f_2(B)$ where $B$ is the closed unit ball (compact) and the $f_i$ are continuous.

About simple connectedness: note that $M=f_1(B^\circ) \cup f_2(B^\circ)$ is an open cover with two simply connected (contractible, really!) open subsets. By van Kampen, it’s enough to show that $f_1(B^\circ) \cap f_2(B^\circ)$ is connected.

Now, by continuity of the $f_i$ and openness, there exists $r <1$ such that $f_i((r,r^{-1})\partial B) \subset f_{3-i}(rB^\circ)$.

It is enough to show that $U_0=B^\circ \cap f_2^{-1}(f_1(B^\circ))$ is connected. Note that $U_0 \supset (r,1)\partial B:=U_1$ (let $y$ be some point in $(r,1)\partial B$. Now, let $x \in U_0$. Then $f_1^{-1}(f_2(x)) \in B^\circ$ so there is a path $p:[0,1] \rightarrow M$ from $f_2(x)$ to $f_2(y)$ not meeting $f_1(\partial B)$.

Let $I=\{t \in [0,1],\, p([0,t]) \subset f_2(B^\circ)\}$. $I$ is the connected component of $0$ in $p^{-1}(f_2(B^\circ))$ so it is an open interval (ie open in $[0,1]$) containing zero. Now, $I$ is contained in the compact $p^{-1}(f_2(B))$, so that if $s$ is the supremum of $I$, there is $0<t\leq s$ such that $t \in I$ and $\|f_2(p(t))\| > r$.

(If $s=1$, $t=1$ works).

Then $f_2^{-1} \circ p$ is defined on $[0,t]$ and has values in $B^\circ \backslash f_2^{-1}(f_1(\partial B))$, so, since $x \in f_2^{-1}(f_1(B^\circ))$, $p$ has values in $f_1(B^\circ)$ as well, so that $x$ is connected to $U_1$ in $U_0$.

So all of $U_0$ is connected to $U_1$, which is connected, so $U_0$ is connected. QED.